# widget case that doesn't work with Oreo 8.1 - message received: W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent

Tags: android, android-widget

My widget app is running fine on all android version except 8 Oreo.
I get a `W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent` message.

There is an interesting blog from CommonsWare but I don't fully understand why it applies to my case. 
https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html

My case looks pretty simple: I have a widget with a button and I want to change the text's button when it is clicked.

What is the right way to fix this issue?

TestWidget.java

```
public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static RemoteViews views;
    private static boolean buttonClicked = false;
    public static final String ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE = "AUTO_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE))
        {
                Log.i("TESTWID", "get onReceive");
        }
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wid_btn_tst, setButton(context));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.i("TESTWID", "onupdate ");

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    public static PendingIntent setButton(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("TEST");
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, TestWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);
    }

}
```

TestWidgetReceiver.java

```
public class TestWidgetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static boolean isButtonON = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("TESTWID", "onReceive "+intent.getAction());

        if(intent.getAction().equals("TEST")){
            updateWidgetButton(context, 2);
        }
    }

    private void updateWidgetButton(Context context, int index) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);
        if(index == 2) {
            if(isButtonON) {
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.wid_btn_tst, "Test Off");
                isButtonON = false;
            }
            else{
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.wid_btn_tst, "Test On");
                isButtonON = true;
            }
        }

        TestWidget.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Test"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".TestWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="AUTO_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/test_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".TestWidgetReceiver"
            android:label="widgetBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="TEST" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/test_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's subtle, but it is because of the *implicit* broadcast being used to trigger your `TestWidgetReceiver`.  It is implicit because it is only specifying the action portion of the `Intent`.  Make the broadcast `Intent` *explicit* by specifying the receiver class in the constructor:

```
public static PendingIntent setButton(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestWidgetReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("TEST");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: You are my hero! How did you learn all that? This implicit broadcast notion is nebulous: I need to read about it. Many thanks!

Comment: And why did Android dev do that: breaking backward compatibility? Was my code poorly written?

Comment: It was done mainly to reduce process thrashing and battery consumption. Since an app process can be started by a broadcast, this could cause lots of processes to spin up frequently, even when they really aren't needed.

Comment: It's not that your code was poorly written, just that Google/AOSP continues to refine and tighten up trouble spots over time and this was found to be a big one. You should also be able to better secure your app's handling using the explicit `Intent` and removing the intent filter and action completely. That will make your receiver private to your app, so nothing else can send it an `Intent`.

Comment: how do you stay on top of such changes? if this is not a secret ;)

Comment: LOL. It can be overwhelming, but reviewing release notes / doc updates with new releases, and often by learning the hard way like you have!

Answer (score 1):

Things are changed now a days in Android. For the security & battery consumption google  introduced so many ways & increased some problem for developers.
You haven't passed the Context of the `TestWidgetReceiver.class` to you intent.

You can do it like that in java

`Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestWidgetReceiver.class);`

or in kotlin

`val intent = Intent(context, TestWidgetReceiver.class);`

You can read more changes here

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

Regards